# What type of neural network should I use?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, deep-learning, lstm, recurrent-neural-network

I'm starting a project where I use a neural network to generate music. I was wondering what type of network I should consider, given the specifications of my sample. Here is what I am working with.

The music I am training is meant to be played as an instruction set by classic Nintendo soundchips. So, obviously, my training set takes that same format. Here is what one line of instructions looks like:

> ROW 00 : E-1 00 F P80 V00 ... : B-0 00 F P80 V00 ... : D-5 00 . P80 : 1-# 00 F V00

which I can basically parse into values that correspond to the pitch and volume of the certain instruments being used. Ie, we can change this to something like an array like

> [16, 15, 11, 15, 90, 1, 15]

or something, just ballparking. Anyways, these instructions get fed into the soundchip emulator at a pretty quick rate (like 256 for 3 measures of song). Thus, the entire song can be represented as just one *long* 2-D array.

In what I've read, LSTM is a pretty popular strategy for music generation, but I was wondering if I can do something like minimizing loss on a 2-D array that represents the entire song? Since there are so many instructions being sent per song, is it reasonable to use LSTM? Should I change from training full songs to making a few measures at a time?

I also would like to do this project from scratch, without using a library. I would like it to be difficult and faithful to doing realistic neural network creation, but I don't want it to be *insanely* hard. Thanks. If you have any resources on how to approach this type of thing, let me know!

Answer (score 3):

I would recommend using a recurrent neural network (or LSTM) for this problem as it would be the most suitable option. Rather than pass in the entire song, it would be better to tokenise your input into sequences of a certain length, which would make it more efficient to train.

Here's some useful resources I found on the topic:

- [Training a Recurrent Neural Network to Compose Music](https://maraoz.com/2016/02/02/abc-rnn/)
- [Composing Music With Recurrent Neural Networks](http://www.hexahedria.com/2015/08/03/composing-music-with-recurrent-neural-networks/)

Answer (score 1):

I worked some time on a project related to music generation so there are some thoughts:

1. RNN are really the best way to predict music.
2. I tried to detect batches via original ticks (but you need to figure our how you will go from one tick to another)
3. One idea more I found in the web and worked with: I split notes sequences (gaps) and lengths.

Links in the previous answer are a good start.

If you want to make it not insanely hard: split your arrays into notes gaps and lengths; split into batches; add 2 RNN layers for gaps ad lengths; train your data. Sometimes the model can stack and zero-gap (predict one note) but here data cleaning may help.

Wish you the best!